# Best way to retry a transaction with Seam & Hibernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, transactions, seam, transaction-isolation

I've got a Seam web application working with Seam & Hibernate (JDBC to SQLServer).

It's working well, but under heavy load (stress test with JMeter), I have some `LockAcquisitionException` or `OptimisticLockException`.

The `LockAquisitionException` is caused by a `SQLServerException` *"Transaction (Process ID 64) was deadlock on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. **Rerun the transaction**"*.

I've then written a Seam Interceptor to rerun such transactions for `LockAquisitionException` :

```java
@AroundInvoke
public Object aroundInvoke(final InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
    if (instanceThreadLocal.get() == null && isMethodInterceptable(invocationContext)) {
        try {
            instanceThreadLocal.set(this);

            int i = 0;
            PersistenceException exception = null;
            do {
                try {
                    return invocationContext.proceed();
                } catch (final PersistenceException e) {
                    final Throwable cause = e.getCause();
                    if (!(cause instanceof LockAcquisitionException)) {
                        throw e;
                    }
                    exception = e;
                    i++;
                    if (i < MAX_RETRIES_LOCK_ACQUISITION) {
                        log.info("Swallowing a LockAcquisitionException - #0/#1", i, MAX_RETRIES_LOCK_ACQUISITION);
                        try {
                            if (Transaction.instance().isRolledBackOrMarkedRollback()) {
                                Transaction.instance().rollback();
                            }
                            Transaction.instance().begin();
                        } catch (final Exception e2) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Exception while rollback the current transaction, and begining a new one.", e2);
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } else {
                        log.info("Can't swallow any more LockAcquisitionException (#0/#1), will throw it.", i, MAX_RETRIES_LOCK_ACQUISITION);
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            } while (i < MAX_RETRIES_LOCK_ACQUISITION);

            throw exception;

        } finally {
            instanceThreadLocal.remove();
        }
    }
    return invocationContext.proceed();
}
```

First question : **do you think this interceptor will correctly do the job ?**

By googling around and saw that [Alfresco](http://www.koders.com/java/fid249E28267D98E75C62D00C627BCB92D6FD888F82.aspx?s=hibernate#L43) ([with a forum talk here](http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=21366)), [Bonita](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ow2.bonita/bonita-server/5.4.2/org/ow2/bonita/services/impl/RetryInterceptor.java#RetryInterceptor) and [Orchestra](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ow2.orchestra/orchestra-core/4.7.1/org/ow2/orchestra/services/commands/RetryInterceptor.java) have some methods to rerun such transactions too, and they are catching much more Exceptions, like `StaleObjectStateException` for instance (the cause of my `OptimisticLockException`).

My 2nd question follows : for the `StaleObjectStateException` (*"Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)"*), normaly you can't just rerun the transaction, as it's a problem of synchronisation with the database and `@Version` fields isn't it ? Why Alfresco for instance tries to rerun such Transactions caused by such Exceptions ?

EDIT :
For `LockAcquisitionException` caused by `SQLServerException`, I've looked at some some resources on the web, and even if I should double check my code, it seems that it can happend anyway ... here are the links :

- [An article on the subject](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/16/sql-server-fix-error-1205-transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-rerun-the-transaction) (with a [comment](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/16/sql-server-fix-error-1205-transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-rerun-the-transaction/#comment-127607) which says it can happend by running out of resources also)
- [Another article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/194f18b0-03b2-4e8f-8c67-5c92373c3efd/) with sublinks :

  - [Microsoft talking about that on support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832524/en-us)
  - [A way to profile transactions](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/10920_3490086_2)
  - [And some advice to reduce such problems](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/deadlocks/)

Even Microsoft says *"Although deadlocks can be minimized, they cannot be completely avoided. That is why the front-end application should be designed to handle deadlocks."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I finally found how to dodge the famous *"Transaction (Process ID 64) was deadlock on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction"*.

So I will not really answer my question but I will explain what I saw and how I manage to do that.

At first, I thought that I had a "lock escalation problem" which would transform my row locks into page locks and produce my deadlocks (my JMeter test runs on a scenario which does delete / update while selecting rows, but the deletes and updates don't concern necessarily the same rows as the selects).

So I read [Lock Escalation in SQL2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/05/17/lock-escalation.aspx) and [How to resolve blocking problems that are caused by lock escalation in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323630/en-us?fr=1) (by MS) and finally [Diagnose SQL Server performance issues using sp_lock](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/diagnose-sql-server-performance-issues-using-splock/321).

But before trying to detect if I was in a lock escalation situation, I fall on that page : http://community.jboss.org/message/95300. It talks about "**transaction isolation**" and that SQLServer has a special one which is called "**snapshot isolation**".

I then found [Using Snapshot Isolation with SQL Server and Hibernate](http://blog.grogscave.net/2010/10/using-snapshot-isolation-with-sql.html) and read [Using Snapshot Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28VS.80%29.aspx) (by MS).

So I first enabled the "snapshot isolation mode" on my database :

```sql
ALTER DATABASE [MY_DATABASE]
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

ALTER DATABASE [MY_DATABASE]
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Then I had to define transaction isolation for JDBC driver to `4096` ... and by reading the book "Hibernate in Action" on paragraph "5.1.6 Setting an isolation level", it reads :

> Note that Hibernate never changes the isolation level of connections obtained from a datasource provided by the application server in a managed environment. **You may change the default isolation using the configuration of your application server**.

So I read [Configuring JDBC DataSources (for JBoss 4)](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connectors_on_JBoss-Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html) and finally edited my `database-ds.xml` file to add this :

```xml
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>myDatasource</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://BDDSERVER\SQL2008;databaseName=DATABASE</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <user-name>user</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
    <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>400</max-pool-size>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>60000</blocking-timeout-millis>
    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
    <background-validation-minutes>2</background-validation-minutes>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <prefill>true</prefill>
    <prepared-statement-cache-size>75</prepared-statement-cache-size>
    <transaction-isolation>4096</transaction-isolation>
</local-tx-datasource>
```

The most important part is of course **`<transaction-isolation>4096</transaction-isolation>`**.

And then, I got no more deadlock problem anymore ! ... so my question is now more or less useless for me ... but perhaps someone could have a real answer !